# Making Multiple Json Requests

Tags: android, json

I want to make 7 JSON Requests in one single activity. Is there any way to do it?
If there is any way to achieve it using volley?

Comment: show your efforts please

Comment: 7 JSON requests that's huge.  What you have tried?

Answer (score 1):

You can run parallel `JSONObjectRequest`s by setting their tags. For example lets say you want to send requests using loop. You will do something like following:

```
for (int i = 0; i < requestSize; i++)
{
StringRequest request = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST,
                    AppUrls.URL_SAVE_SAVE_DATA, new Response.Listener<String>() {

                @Override
                public void onResponse(String response) {
                    String status = "";
                    JSONObject json = null;
                    try {
                        json = new JSONObject(response);
                        if(json != null && json.has(JSONParsor.STATUS))
                            status = json.getString(JSONParsor.STATUS);
                        if(status != null && status.length() > 0 && status.equalsIgnoreCase("success"))
                        {
                        }
                        else {
                        }
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }

            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                }
            })

            {
                @Override
                protected Map<String, String> getParams() {
                    Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
                    params.put(JSONParsor.DATA_STRING, jsonObject.toString());
                    return params;

                }

            };

            request.setTag("TAG_" + i);
            addToRequestQueue(request);
}
```

In response, you can return the request id and then you can match, which request belongs to which tag.

Hope this helps.